# Making a 4 section CSS fixed navbar, running into layout issues

Tags: html, css, navbar

I'm trying to make a fixed navbar at the top of my webpage, it's all pure HTML and CSS for now. The problem comes as a result of the fact that I want a button on the left side to open up a sidebar for navigation on mobile. I want to position the three navbar items in the center of the navbar, evenly spaced from eachother. As previously stated, I also want the navbar to be fixed so that it is visible no matter where the user scrolls on the page.

Here's the HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>Cyberpunk Bar</title>
  <link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootswatch/4.1.1/lux/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-4KIc2mnKfAA7VjirNLk2Sqp7jxFNq1q8+FhYGxhW2l52lt4HJsfksL+hjswHfbl/" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.13/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-DNOHZ68U8hZfKXOrtjWvjxusGo9WQnrNx2sqG0tfsghAvtVlRW3tvkXWZh58N9jp" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>

<div id="navbar">

      <ul id="navbar-menu">
        <li>
          <span class="open-slide">
            <a href="#" onclick="">
              <div><i id="open-button" class="fab fa-bitcoin"></i></div>
            </a>
          </span>
        </li>

        <li><a href="#section1">Theme</a></li>
        <li><a href="#section2">Beer</a></li>
        <li><a href="#section3">Menu</a><li>
      </ul>
</div>

<body>
  <div class="pimg1">
  <div class="ptext">
    <span class="border">Cyberpunk Bar and Grill</span>
  </div>
</div>

<section class="section section-light">
  <h2>Section 1</h2>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Dolor enim quis explicabo perspiciatis nemo nesciunt ducimus, aut eos iste modi amet, illo est eveniet at porro debitis excepturi neque nisi! <br>
   <p>Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Eaque neque expedita at fugit voluptates veritatis temporibus ab dignissimos et nihil? Repellendus debitis possimus consectetur facilis nostrum natus fugit voluptatibus modi?</p>
</section>

<div class="pimg2">
  <div class="ptext">
    <span class="border">Brilliant Beer Selection</span>
  </div>
</div>

<section class="section section-light">
  <h2>Section 2</h2>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Dolor enim quis explicabo perspiciatis nemo nesciunt ducimus, aut eos iste modi amet, illo est eveniet at porro debitis excepturi neque nisi! <br>
   <p>Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Eaque neque expedita at fugit voluptates veritatis temporibus ab dignissimos et nihil? Repellendus debitis possimus consectetur facilis nostrum natus fugit voluptatibus modi?</p>
  </p>
</section>

<div class="pimg3">
  <div class="ptext">
    <span class="border">Burgers and Steak</span>
  </div>
</div>

<section id="section3" class="section section-dark">
  <h2>Section 3</h2>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Dolor enim quis explicabo perspiciatis nemo nesciunt ducimus, aut eos iste modi amet, illo est eveniet at porro debitis excepturi neque nisi! <br>
   <p>Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Eaque neque expedita at fugit voluptates veritatis temporibus ab dignissimos et nihil? Repellendus debitis possimus consectetur facilis nostrum natus fugit voluptatibus modi?</p>
</section>

<div class="pimg4">
  <div class="ptext">
    <span class="border">What are you waiting for?</span>
  </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Here's the CSS

```
body, html
{
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-family: "Lato", sans-serif;
  font-weight: 400;
  line-height: 1.8em;
  color: #666;
}

#navbar
{
  height: 100px;
  background-color: black;
  z-index: 1;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 10;
  filter:drop-shadow(0 5px 15px black);
}

#navbar-menu
{
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  list-style: none;
  font-size: 25px;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  color: white;
}

#open-button
{
  color: white;
  font-size: 50px;
  padding-bottom: 25px;
  padding-top: 25px;
}

#open-button:hover
{
  color: #666;
}

.pimg1, .pimg2, .pimg3, .pimg4
{
  position: relative;
  opacity: 0.70;
  background-position: center;
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
/*   fixed = parallax, scroll = normal */
  background-attachment: fixed;
}

.pimg1
{
  background-image:url('https://i.imgur.com/bHJ4vHL.jpg?1');
  min-height: 100%;
}

.pimg2
{
  background-image:url('https://images.pexels.com/photos/338711/pexels-photo-338711.jpeg?cs=srgb&dl=alcohol-alcoholic-alcoholic-beverage-338711.jpg&fm=jpg');
  min-height: 400px;
}

.pimg3
{
  background-image:url('https://images.pexels.com/photos/156114/pexels-photo-156114.jpeg?cs=srgb&dl=beef-bread-burger-156114.jpg&fm=jpg');
  min-height: 400px;
}

.pimg4
{
  background-image:url('https://images.pexels.com/photos/696218/pexels-photo-696218.jpeg?cs=srgb&dl=adult-bar-blur-696218.jpg&fm=jpg');
  min-height: 400px;
}

.section
{
  text-align: center;
  padding: 50px 80px;
}

.section-light
{
  background-color: #f4f4f4;
  color: #666;
}

.section-dark
{
  background-color: #282E34;
  color: #DDD;
}

.ptext
{
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  color: #000;
  font-size: 32px;
  letter-spacing: 8px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.ptext .border
{
  background-color: #111;
  color: white;
  padding: 20px;
}
```

Is using a  the best practice for this? Please help!

Answer (score 0):

First of all our `<div id="navbar">` have to be inside `<body>` tag.
Check here for edited parts of code:
HTML:

```
<body>
   <div id="navbar">
     <ul id="navbar-menu">
       <li>
         <span class="open-slide">
           <a href="#" onclick="">
            <div><i id="open-button" class="fab fa-bitcoin"></i></div>
           </a>
         </span>
       </li>
       <li><a href="#section1">Theme</a></li>
       <li><a href="#section2">Beer</a></li>
       <li><a href="#section3">Menu</a><li>
     </ul>
   </div>

      .....

  </body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
#navbar {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: black;
  z-index: 1;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 10;
  filter:drop-shadow(0 5px 15px black);
}
#navbar-menu {
  width: max-content;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
#navbar-menu li {
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  list-style: none;
  font-size: 25px;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0 40px;
  color: white;
}
```

https://codepen.io/Yulia_pi/pen/yjRQgy

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(".open-slide").click(function() {
  $(this).toggleClass("opend");
});
```

```css
body,
html {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-family: "Lato", sans-serif;
  font-weight: 400;
  line-height: 1.8em;
  color: #666;
}

#navbar {
  height: 100px;
  background-color: black;
  z-index: 1;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 10;
  filter: drop-shadow(0 5px 15px black);
}

#navbar-menu {
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  list-style: none;
  font-size: 25px;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  color: white;
}

#open-button {
  color: white;
  font-size: 50px;
  padding-bottom: 25px;
  padding-top: 25px;
  display:none;
}

#open-button:hover {
  color: #666;
}

.pimg1 {
  /*margin-top:100px;*/
}

.pimg1,
.pimg2,
.pimg3,
.pimg4 {
  position: relative;
  opacity: 0.70;
  background-position: center;
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  /*   fixed = parallax, scroll = normal */
  background-attachment: fixed;
}

.pimg1 {
  background-image: url('https://i.imgur.com/bHJ4vHL.jpg?1');
  min-height: 100%;
}

.pimg2 {
  background-image: url('https://images.pexels.com/photos/338711/pexels-photo-338711.jpeg?cs=srgb&dl=alcohol-alcoholic-alcoholic-beverage-338711.jpg&fm=jpg');
  min-height: 400px;
}

.pimg3 {
  background-image: url('https://images.pexels.com/photos/156114/pexels-photo-156114.jpeg?cs=srgb&dl=beef-bread-burger-156114.jpg&fm=jpg');
  min-height: 400px;
}

.pimg4 {
  background-image: url('https://images.pexels.com/photos/696218/pexels-photo-696218.jpeg?cs=srgb&dl=adult-bar-blur-696218.jpg&fm=jpg');
  min-height: 400px;
}

.section {
  text-align: center;
  padding: 50px 80px;
}

.section-light {
  background-color: #f4f4f4;
  color: #666;
}

.section-dark {
  background-color: #282E34;
  color: #DDD;
}

.ptext {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  color: #000;
  font-size: 32px;
  letter-spacing: 8px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.ptext .border {
  background-color: #111;
  color: white;
  padding: 20px;
}

/* new css */

.open-slide {
  display: none;
}

#navbar-menu {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -moz-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-flex-flow: row wrap;
  justify-content: space-around;
}

#navbar-menu>li {
  height: 100px;
  line-height: 100px;
}

.menus-nav.fixed-header {
  position: fixed;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 1030;
}

@media(max-width:767px) {
  .open-slide {
    display: block;
  }
  .open-slide+#navbar-menu {
    max-height: 0;
    position: relative;
    -webkit-transition: max-height 1000ms ease;
    transition: max-height 1000ms ease;
    overflow: hidden;
  }
  .open-slide.opend+#navbar-menu {
    max-height: 300px;
  }
  #navbar {
    height: auto;
  }
  #navbar-menu {
    display: block !important;
    display: block !important;
    display: block !important;
    display: block !important;
    display: block !important;
    -webkit-flex-flow: inherit !important;
    justify-content: inherit !important;
  }
  #navbar-menu>li {
    height: auto;
  }
  #navbar-menu>li {
    height: auto;
    line-height: 1em;
    padding: 10px 15px;
    text-align: left;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #222222;
  }
 #open-button {
   display:block;
 }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/todc-bootstrap/3.3.7-3.3.13/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/todc-bootstrap/3.3.7-3.3.13/js/bootstrap.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.13/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-DNOHZ68U8hZfKXOrtjWvjxusGo9WQnrNx2sqG0tfsghAvtVlRW3tvkXWZh58N9jp" crossorigin="anonymous">

<body>
  <!-- menu -->
  <div id="navbar" class="menus-nav fixed-header">
    <i id="open-button" class="fab fa-bitcoin open-slide" onclick=""></i>

    <ul id="navbar-menu">
      <li><a href="#section1">Theme</a></li>
      <li><a href="#section2">Beer</a></li>
      <li><a href="#section3">Menu</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <!-- menu -->

  <div class="pimg1">
    <div class="ptext">
      <span class="border">Cyberpunk Bar and Grill</span>
    </div>
  </div>

  <section class="section section-light">
    <h2>Section 1</h2>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Dolor enim quis explicabo perspiciatis nemo nesciunt ducimus, aut eos iste modi amet, illo est eveniet at porro debitis excepturi neque nisi! <br>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Eaque neque expedita at fugit voluptates veritatis temporibus ab dignissimos et nihil? Repellendus debitis possimus consectetur facilis nostrum natus fugit voluptatibus modi?</p>
  </section>

  <div class="pimg2">
    <div class="ptext">
      <span class="border">Brilliant Beer Selection</span>
    </div>
  </div>

  <section class="section section-light">
    <h2>Section 2</h2>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Dolor enim quis explicabo perspiciatis nemo nesciunt ducimus, aut eos iste modi amet, illo est eveniet at porro debitis excepturi neque nisi! <br>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Eaque neque expedita at fugit voluptates veritatis temporibus ab dignissimos et nihil? Repellendus debitis possimus consectetur facilis nostrum natus fugit voluptatibus modi?
      </p>
  </section>

  <div class="pimg3">
    <div class="ptext">
      <span class="border">Burgers and Steak</span>
    </div>
  </div>

  <section id="section3" class="section section-dark">
    <h2>Section 3</h2>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Dolor enim quis explicabo perspiciatis nemo nesciunt ducimus, aut eos iste modi amet, illo est eveniet at porro debitis excepturi neque nisi! <br>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Eaque neque expedita at fugit voluptates veritatis temporibus ab dignissimos et nihil? Repellendus debitis possimus consectetur facilis nostrum natus fugit voluptatibus modi?</p>
  </section>

  <div class="pimg4">
    <div class="ptext">
      <span class="border">What are you waiting for?</span>
    </div>
  </div>

</body>
```